# why axios call my api in http when i use a https adress

Tags: api, vue.js, heroku, mixed-content

Here is the error I get when i'm calling the api

[image]

my function :
[image]

all my route work except this one i don't know why

Comment: somewhere in the application you are trying to hit http://sportmanagementsystemapi.herokuapp.com/api/user check for all the occurence of api endpoints used

Comment: Try opening https://sportmanagementsystemapi.herokuapp.com/api/user/ directly in your browser — that is, `https://sportmanagementsystemapi.herokuapp.com/api/user/`, with `https` as the protocol. You’ll find that you get redirected to `http://sportmanagementsystemapi.herokuapp.com/api/user/` — that is, plain http, non-https. The same thing happens with the axios.post request in your code — it gets redirected to that non-https URL. And that’s why you get that mixed-content error.

Comment: @sideshowbarker How are you changing that? in the api or in my vue project ?

Comment: The `sportmanagementsystemapi.herokuapp.com` server needs to be changed, to make it not redirect from https to http

Answer (score 1):

i resolved the problem in my vuejs project i write "https://sportmanagementsystemapi.herokuapp.com/api/user/" the probleme was the "/" at the end is just witre like this "https://sportmanagementsystemapi.herokuapp.com/api/user" and that working